# How get a class in Swift to save values

Tags: swift, class, accessor

Hello i have a UITableViewController, in the master view is a list which step can be select, in the detail view u can select and enter values. How can i save the values in a separated swift class in the project which i can to use the values in other views

I know that in C# is easy to make a class with set and get to save same information but in swift i don't know how i can realize???

```
public class ValueClass {

public static var Mi:String {
    get {
        return self.Mi
    }
    set (newVal) {
        self.Mi = newVal
    }
}
}
```

but i get always a error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just declare a struct with a static variable, the getter and setter are for free

```
struct ValueClass {
  static var mi = ""
}

// set
ValueClass.mi = "Hello"
// get
ValueClass.mi
```